# GWT: How to Apply css to only first letter of my LABEL

Tags: css, gwt

I have a requirement to put a color on the specific letter of label in GWT .

For example one of my label says "Hello"

So it should be like *H*ello, so the "H" is colored blue and "ello" will remain black ..

can i achieve this ?

```
                Label lbl = new Label("Hello");
                lbl.setStyleName("lblStyle");
```

Now H should be  BLUE color in out put and ello  should be black
In another schenario  He  should be blue  and "llo" shold be black

thanks

Comment: post some code will help us to solve issue

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](http://jsbin.com/oFOGedE/1/edit)

[This will help you](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_style_with_css.htm)

```
:first-letter
{ 
color:Blue;
}
```

Comment: @junaidp is your problem solved? if there any issue please post some code :)